# Inner div with background doesn't affected by outer div with border-radius

Tags: html, css

I applied `border` with `border-radius` to `li`. The background applied to `a`. The issue is that the `a` corners are still showing up.

Is there any solutions you can think of aside from the following?

Two possible solutions:

1. Use `overflow:hidden`.
   *This solution doesn't apply to my current layout so I need other solution.*
2. Apply `border-radius` to both `li` and `a`. *This is my only solution at this moment but I need at least to lessen css codes on my project...*

note: the tab layout is pixel perfect so I am using this method.

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/ocuz6r44/)

```css
body {
  background:#eee
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  border:1px solid #aaa;
  border-bottom:0;
  border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
ul li a {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin-bottom:-1px;
}
ul li.active a {
  background:#fff;
}

.content {
  border:1px solid #aaa;background:#fff;height:200px
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">tab2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">tab3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">tab4</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="content"></div>
```

Comment: Just apply the `background` style to the `<li>` elements?

Comment: If I do that, the border-bottom of the active menu will show up. I'll provide a fiddle.

Comment: The problem is in active a element only. Apply border-radius to your ul li.active a, this will definitely fix the problem.

Comment: @Kiran, that's actually my solution atm as I mentioned already. But maybe there's another solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1gm00L3z/)

```
body {
  background:#eee
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
ul li a {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin-bottom:-1px;
  border:1px solid #aaa;
  border-bottom:0;
  border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
}
ul li.active a {
  background:#fff;
}

.content {
  border:1px solid #aaa;background:#fff;height:200px
}
```

Comment: oh you switched the border from li to li a. I'll try if it doesn't affect my other css :) thanks

Comment: This might be the best solution, I'll just have to rewrite my current css :) I just don't know why I didn't tried this before lol..

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to apply the `border-radius` to both parent and child. I don't think this is a major problem tho, it doesn't look like you have too much CSS.

I guess you can reduce the amount of CSS by using two selectors separated by a `,` if you aren't doing that already.

If you don't need the background to be specifically on the child anchor, you can do as @Phylogenesis said and apply it to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to edit styles of **"a"** so a solution is to force children to inherit parents styles:

```
ul li * {border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;}
```

Comment: This is essentially the same solution.

Comment: Thanks @Ali ! Nice! I might consider this.

Comment: But keeps the styles of children clean, specially in large scaled and Team-work projects. @bjb568